# Is it okay to curse Satan?

Tags: allah, shaitan

It is Satan's way to whisper wrong things to us. I am not exceptional. Whenever I try to relax a bit, unwanted thoughts come over my mind.

Out of frustration, I cursed Satan. I know Satan is already cursed by Allah.

At the same time cursing is not a proper thing to do for a Muslim. Now what do I do? Will I be punished for this by Allah? If I did wrong, what will happen to me?

Answer (score 1):

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The believer is not one who slanders, curses or utters foul or obscene speech.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi and classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.

And in case of shayatin

It was narrated from Abu’l-Maleeh that a man said:

> I was riding behind the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
> him) when an animal stumbled. I said: “Woe to the Shaytaan.” The
> Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Do not say
> woe to the Shaytaan, for if you say that he grows bigger until he is
> like a house, and he says, ‘It is by my power.’ Rather say:
> ‘Bismillaah (in the name of Allaah),’ for if you say that, he grows
> smaller, until he is like a fly.”

Narrated by Ahmad, 20068; Abu Dawood, 4982; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.

So If you wanna harm the shayatin then do Zikr and good deeds. But don't curse the Shayatin.